# if $y_1=\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt x}$ is solution of $x^2y''+xy'+(x^2-1/4)y=3 \sqrt x^3 \sin x$, find the other lineraly independent solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

If $y_1=\displaystyle\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt x}$ is a solution of the differential equation $$x^2y'' + xy' + \left(x^2-\frac{1}{4}\right)y=3\sqrt x^3 \sin x,$$ find the other linearly independent solution.

Answer (score 1):

If $y_1(x)$ is obne solution of $y''+p(x)y'+qy=0$, then its other solution is
$$y_2(x)=y_1(x)\int \frac{e^{\int -p(x) dx}}{y_1^2} dx$$
Please chcek that $y_1=\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{x}}$ is also a solution of the HOMOGENEOUS ODE:
$$x^2y''+xy'+(x^2-1/4)y=0\implies y''+\frac{1}{x}y'+(1-\frac{1}{4x^2})y=0,$$
So its other solution is given as
$$y_2(x)=y_1(x)\int x \frac{e^{-\ln x}}{\sin^2 x} dx= y_1(x) \int \csc^2 x dx=-\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{x}} \cot x= -\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{x}}.$$

Further the solution of the inhomogeneous eq. of OP can be solved by the method of variation of parameters by seeking $$Y(x)=C_1(x) y_1(x)+ C_2(x) y_2(x)+D_1 y_1(x)+D_2 y_2(x)$$

See:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters

Answer (score 1):

Set, inspired by the given solution and the form of the right side, $u(x)=\sqrt{x}y(x)$. Then its derivatives are
\begin{align}
u'(x)&=\sqrt{x}y'(x)+\frac1{2\sqrt x}y(x)\\
u''(x)&=\sqrt{x}y''(x)+\frac1{\sqrt x}y'(x)-\frac1{4\sqrt x^3}y(x)
\end{align}
so that inserted into the given equation
$$
\sqrt x^3u''(x)=x^2y''(x)+xy'(x)-\frac14y(x)=\sqrt x^3(3\sin x - u(x)) 
$$
Now cancelling again the common factor one is left with
$$
u''(x)+u(x)=3\sin(x)
$$
which is a standard forced harmonic oscillator (with resonance).

Comment: For singular equations like this one, one has to decide for one of the domains $x<0$ or $x>0$. When not mentioned, the natural choice is $x>0$ where then also the rational powers are well-defined.

Comment: It stands for $(\sqrt x)^3$, I see nothing unusual in this. Other variants are of course $\sqrt{x^3}$ and $x^{3/2}$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann is this full solution for this equation?

Comment: @Aryadeva is this full solution for this equation?

Comment: You need to solve the last equation Lutz has posted. @farnaz  and find the particular solution  $u''(x)+u(x)=3\sin(x)$ That's easier in that form.

Comment: @Aryadeva thank you

Comment: @farnaz for the equation Lutz posted you have this guess : $$u_p =Ax\cos x$$ Find the constant A by plugging this in the differential equation. Then use this result :$u_p(x)=\sqrt{x}y_p(x)$ to get $y_p$

Comment: @Aryadeva Thank you! your explanation was very helpful.

Comment: @farnaz you are very welcome Farnaz.